# Little NumPad in tkinter

Tags: python, variables, numbers, tkinter

I'm trying to build a little num pad using tkinter, to be able to enter a password code on a pure touchsystem. This is what I have so far:

import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk

```
def main():
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    numpad = NumPad(root)
    root.mainloop()


btn_list = [
'7',  '8',  '9',
'4',  '5',  '6',
'1',  '2',  '3', '0']


class NumPad(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, root)
        self.grid()
        self.numpad_create()

    def numpad_create(self):
        r = 1
        c = 0
        for b in btn_list:
            cmd= lambda: print(b)
            self.b= ttk.Button(self, text=b,width=5,command=cmd).grid(row=r,column=c)
            print(b)
            c += 1
            if c > 4:
                c = 0
                r += 1

main()
```

If I start the programm, it prints the numbers b to the shell, so this works. Also the Buttons are displayed as wished. But if I click them, I get always 0 as output to the shell. I can't find the mistake I've done, I think it might has something to do with garbage-collecting, but I am not sure though.

Could somebody help me? It would be really great!

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cmd`, your lambda, does not catch the value of `b` when the lambda itself was declared. the final state of `b` is `0`, and that is why all your buttons end up printing `b`.

Answer (score 4):

Your lambda should be specified like this:

```
cmd= lambda b=b: print(b)
```

This will bind the current value of `b` to be the default value of the parameter named `b` in your lambda. Without this binding, the lambda will use the value of `b` at the time it is pressed rather than the value at the time it was created.

Personally I find it confusing to use the same variable in both contexts; I personally would write it like this, which is functionally identical but a little easier to understand:

```
cmd= lambda button=b: print(button)
```

Answer (score 0):

The for loop in `NumPad.numpad_create` loops over each of the button numbers and stores them in `self.b`.  The problem is that each number overwrites the previous value of `self.b`, so that the only value that is actually stored is `0`.  tkinter automatically garbage collects objects that do not have a live reference.  Add another attribute to `NumPad` which is a list and put all of your button objects into it.

@thkang is also right: I think that there are two separate bugs.  Note that I haven't actually tested this.